# How to use geom_smooth() on a subset of variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two groups of variables, and plotting them on different graphs yields this:
[image]

So, I now have two graphs: one with an empty bottom half, another with an empty top half. I want to combine these to have a single graph, with two grey bands for the two groups of variables. I have searched a lot, but I still can't figure out exactly how to do this. My current code is:

```
categories <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

# To stop ggplot from imposing alphabetical ordering on x-axis
categories <- factor(categories, levels=categories, ordered=T)

intensive   <- c( 0.660,  0.438,  0.515,  0.038,  0.443)
comparative <- c( 0.361,  0.928,  0.270,  0.285,  0.311)
wh_adverbs  <- c( 0.431,  0.454,  0.056,  0.330,  0.577)
past_tense    <- c(0.334, 0.229, 0.668, 0.566, 0.838)
present_tense <- c(0.659, 0.322, 0.484, 0.039, 1.000) 
conjunctions <- c( 0.928,  0.207,  0.162, -0.299, -0.045)
personal      <- c(0.498, 0.521, 0.332, 0.04, 0.04)
interrogative <- c(0.266, 0.202, 0.236, 0.06, 0.06)
sbj_objective <- c(0.913, 0.755, 0.863, 0.803, 0.913)
possessive    <- c(0.896, 0.802, 0.960, 0.611, 0.994)
thrd_person <- c(-0.244, -0.265, -0.410, -0.008, -0.384)
nouns       <- c(-0.602, -0.519, -0.388, -0.244, -0.196)

df1 <- data.frame(categories,
                 "Intensive Adverbs"=intensive,
                 "Comparative Adverbs"=comparative,
                 "Wh-adverbs (WRB)"=wh_adverbs,
                 "Verb: Past Tense"=past_tense,
                 "Verb: Present Tense"=present_tense,
                 "Conjunctions"=conjunctions,
                 "Personal Pronouns"=personal,
                 "Interrogative Pronouns"=interrogative,
                 "Subjective/Objective Pronouns"=sbj_objective,
                 "Possessive Pronouns"=possessive,
                 "3rd-person verbs"=thrd_person,
                 "Nouns"=nouns,
                 check.names=F
                 )

df1.m <- melt(df1)
g1 <- ggplot(df1.m, aes(group=1, categories, value, shape=variable, colour=variable))
g1 <- g1 + geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=4, color="white")
g1 <- g1 + geom_point(aes(shape=variable), size=2, alpha=I(0.8))
g1 <- g1 + scale_shape_manual(values = 1:12)
g1 <- g1 + geom_smooth()
g1 <- g1 + scale_x_discrete("\n(a) Involved features", expand=c(0.05, 0.05))
g1 <- g1 + coord_cartesian(ylim=(c(-1,1)))
g1 <- g1 + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,1), name="Log Odds Ratio", oob=rescale_none)
g1 <- g1 + guides(colour=guide_legend(title=NULL), shape=guide_legend(title=NULL))
g1 <- g1 + theme(legend.position="right",
                 legend.justification=c(0,0),
                 legend.text=element_text(size=10),
                 panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                 axis.text=element_text(size=10,color="black"),
                 axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold")
                )
```

But this only plots one of the curves, as shown:
[image]

How can I get both the lines (along with the confidence interval) for both groups of variables?

Edit: Adding another sub-question related to this: if this is possible, is there a way for me to "divide" the legend into two groups as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you saw my note about `coord_cartesian`. But setting both that and `limits` is working at cross-purposes. Anyway, maybe you wanted this:

```
df1.m$grp <- ifelse(df1.m$variable %in% c('3rd-person verbs','Nouns'),'grp1','grp2')
g1 <- ggplot(df1.m, aes(group=grp, categories, value, shape=variable, colour=variable)) + 
        geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=4, color="white") + 
        geom_point(aes(shape=variable), size=2, alpha=I(0.8)) + 
        scale_shape_manual(values = 1:12) + 
        geom_smooth() + 
        scale_x_discrete("\n(a) Involved features", expand=c(0.05, 0.05)) + 
        coord_cartesian(ylim=(c(-1,1))) + 
        scale_y_continuous(name="Log Odds Ratio", oob=rescale_none) + 
        guides(colour=guide_legend(title=NULL), shape=guide_legend(title=NULL)) + 
        theme(legend.position="right",
                 legend.justification=c(0,0),
                 legend.text=element_text(size=10),
                 panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                 axis.text=element_text(size=10,color="black"),
                 axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold")
                )
```

Presumably you're doing things this way because you've decided that faceting isn't what you want...? As for split the legend, that will really only be possible if you make two separate plot on separate subsets of the data and then place them together using `grid.arrange` from the **gridExtra** package.

Comment: I would love to use facets here. But since I already had a non-facet code ready, I thought it'd be easier to modify it a little. Also, probably since I started using R only recently, reading through the facet examples (http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/) has only confused me.